# how to deflate recursively array having a numerical value as the key?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, deflate

I try to deflate recursively array that having a **numerical value as key**. 
The repeating structure is array with keys **AND**, **OR** or **NOT** and within array with numbers as keys. I try to recursively deflate the arrays that are within the keys **AND**, **OR** and **NOT**

I have this :

```
$input=array(
    'Experiment.name' => (int) 0,
    ' AND ' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Experiment.note' => (int) 0
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'Experiment.date' => (int) 0,
            ' AND ' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'Experiment.state' => (int) 0
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

and try to get:

```
$output=array(
    'Experiment.name' => (int) 0,
    ' AND ' => array(       
            'Experiment.note' => (int) 0
            'Experiment.date' => (int) 0,
            ' AND ' => array(
                    'Experiment.state' => (int) 0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The within arrays can have more than two array and the keys  may not be AND, could be **AND**, **OR** AND **NOT**

Comment: `array_merge` seems like it might work

Comment: Yes, thank for help me, but I do not know how to do this with that function.I do not know how to use it to achieve that i want, I do not give succeeded

Comment: Have you tried looking `http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php` here?

Comment: yes, I've looked at the manual and I've tried but I could not do.write it here has been my last choice

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$input[' AND '][0] = array_merge($input[' AND '][0], $input[' AND '][1]);
unset($input[' AND '][1]);
```

Comment: oh thank it's a good option, but only deflates the first array, not performed recursively. Furthermore the key could not be AND. Thanks for help me :)

Comment: That would be pertinent info for the question wouldn't you say?

Comment: I had already written it was recursive,but I just added more information

Comment: The AND keys can be any number of other things other than AND?